# How to differentiate two HTML elements with the same class?

Tags: android, jsoup

I would like to know if there is any method in Jsoup that differentiates multiple elements with the same class. For clarification, consider the following HTML fragment, I need to retrieve the class name "description", but I need to differentiate one information from the other.

```
<Div class = "related-box gray-text no-margin">
<H3 class = "epsilon"> Awards </ h3>

<P class = "description">
<Strong> Sena - 6 </ strong> <br>
There was no
</ P>

<P class = "description">
<Strong> Quina - 5 </ strong> <br>
124 winning bets, R $ 43,174.39
</ P>

<P class = "description">
<Strong> Quadra - 4 </ strong> <br>
8817 winning bets,
</ P>
```

Thank You!

Comment: Too general: for which element are you looking and does the order always remains the same? You can also select the element of interest in the chrome developer tools and select the copy->get selector option from the right click menu.

Comment: Yes, the positions are always identical, there is no change.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to grab the second `<p>`tag in the posted div, you have multiple options. The following examples use the [nth-of-type CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp), the get function for jsoup Elements (inherited from ArrayList) and iterating through the elements, if you need more detailed comparison of the elements contents. There are a lot more options and as mentioned in my comment above, using tools like the chrome developer tools, you can select elements and get a matching selector, which might be a good starting point for generalization.

**Example Code**

```
String source ="<div class='related-box gray-text no-margin'>"+
        "<h3 class='epsilon'>Awards</h3>"
        + "<p class='description'><strong>Sena - 6</strong><br>There was no</p>"
        + "<p class='description'><strong>Quina - 5</strong><br>124 winning bets, R $ 43,174.39</p>"
        + "<p class='description'><strong>Quadra - 4</strong><br>8817 winning bets,</p></div>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(source, "UTF-8");

// nth-of-type(n) CSS selector
Element quina = doc.select(".description:nth-of-type(2)").first();

System.out.println(quina.text());

// Elements.get(n) jsoup method
quina = doc.select(".description").get(1);

System.out.println(quina.text());

// iterate over Elements
Elements descriptions = doc.select(".description");
for (Element element : descriptions) {
    if(element.text().contains("Quina")){
        quina = element;
    }
}

System.out.println(quina.text());
```

**Output**

```
Quina - 5 124 winning bets, R $ 43,174.39
Quina - 5 124 winning bets, R $ 43,174.39
Quina - 5 124 winning bets, R $ 43,174.39
```

Comment: Thank you, Frederic.
I was able to solve the problem with your help !!!

Comment: @Tisco: please consider accepting this as an answer, so the question is marked as answered and for future visitors with similar problems, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.